# How to write automation tests for In App Billing in Android

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I need to write tests to automate the in app billing on Android and validate whether the purchase went through successfully or not. I understand that there are API's to query sku's, products as well as purchases but how should i automate a purchase so that the Google billing dialog automatically process the purchase without even requiring a tap?

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.